# What "platform" should I use to develop an online interactive image map?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flash

I'm trying to create a simple interactive image map where the user would be able to hover the mouse pointer over a part of the image and the setup would in turn animate/show/unhide a pop-up box (not new window!) next to the mouse pointer's current position containing text, images, &| clickable links.

However, in the example, it is not an image map, but 9 small images.  Each image becomes a bit larger when hovered over, and when clicked, loads the image into the right `<div>` of the page.

I'm looking to satisfy these criteria:

- I want to use an image map (HTML or other) instead of 9 small images
- I want the hovering action to also load the image - remove the need to click the image
- I want the page to be viewable & interactive from all popular viewers - desktop browsers, mobile browsers, iPads, Android tablets, etc...

I'm not sure what platform (aka - mix of dev tools) to use in order to satisfy the list of criteria above.  The main goal is for the last item in the list of criteria above to be satisfied.  I could probably sacrifice the first or second criteria from the list above if that's what needs to be done in order to satisfy the last item.

The couple of "platforms" I thought of using were:

- HTML + CSS
- jQuery + CSS
- Flash + Actionscript
- Javascript + AJAX

What set of tools should I use to pull this off?

Is there a different tool or set of tools that I'm missing and should be using instead of the ones listed above?

Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT:** If you vote to close this, please redirect me to the question that already covers this or please don't close it!  This question is answerable - it's not a discussion.

Comment: For iPads Flash is definitely out (although would probably be the easiest, at least for me). I would go with jQuery on this project. As far as pop ups (not pop up windows) I prefer using fancybox, which is a lightbox alternative.

Comment: @ToddBFisher - thanks for the info.  can you provide links for fancybox?  I'm not being lazy, I just want all the pertinent materials for this project to reside in this thread.  THanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple to implement in **straight HTML/CSS** (no JS required), which would be the most widely consumable method.  Here's a simple example:

- Final product: http://csshowto.com/examples/imagemap/
- How to: http://csshowto.com/effects/css-image-maps-with-pop-up-tool-tips/

You could make the pop-up content as sophisticated as you like - this is a fairly rudimentary example but you can use any arbitrary HTML in the list items.  Also, you could sprinkle in some CSS3 animations for the transitions which would look nice and shiny on your fancy modern browsers.

Comment: hahaha - "on your fancy modern browsers". spoken like a true extra-terrestrial.  this is a really good example and great starting point.  thanks

Comment: in this specific example, the maps are rectangles - can the CSS be used to define poly coordinates for the map?

Comment: re: fancy modern browsers - I'm one of those impoverished souls who still has to target features to IE6 a lot of the time so CSS3 still feels *special*.  HTML is a blocky, blocky universe -n on-rectangles are not easily handled (though you can hack circles by using huge `border-radius`).  For arbitrary polygons, you are gonna have to head into SVG or `canvas` territory, which will compound complexity quite a bit.  If you want to head down that path, I would say at a high level, pick SVG if you want to render everything server-side / don't like JS; `canvas` if you like javascript.